# AngularJS PHP restful api cached result

Tags: php, angularjs, rest

I am working on a simple POC task list and I am having trouble with the rest service returning i am assuming are cached results. I log into the application as user X and a task list is returned, when I log out and log in as user Y the task list for user X still displays until I refresh the page. My rest service takes in a user token and pulls back the tasks for that user, when i log the token i can see they are different for each user but before refresh results are the same.

**UPDATE RESOLUTION APPENDED AT END**

Console log results before refresh (f5)

```
API_KEY:: c63bd7f498957746c0af4e717e8e5fc3
Object {id: 13, task: "sfgdsdfg", status: 0, createdAt: "2015-12-05 18:35:00"}
User logout
API_KEY:: 479ba4c2228fad5b6d911e82d34873a1
Object {id: 13, task: "sfgdsdfg", status: 0, createdAt: "2015-12-05 18:35:00"}
```

After refresh

```
API_KEY:: 479ba4c2228fad5b6d911e82d34873a1
Object {id: 1, task: "task goes here", status: 0, createdAt: "2015-12-08 21:14:17"}
```

Here is my angularjs factory i am using to call the GET request:

```
smlServices.factory('UserTasks', function($resource, $window){
    return $resource("http://koding.io/api/index.php/tasks", {}, {
        get: {method: 'GET', cache: false, isArray: false, headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': $window.sessionStorage.token}},
        save: {method: 'POST', cache: false, isArray: false, headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': $window.sessionStorage.token}}
    });
});
```

This is the controller i am calling the factory from:

```
smlControllers.controller("UpdateTasksCtrl", function($scope, UserTasks, $window){
    $scope.title = "Update Tasks";

    console.log($window.sessionStorage.token);
    UserTasks.get(
        {},
        function success(response){
            console.log(response.tasks[0]);
            $scope.tasks = response.tasks;
        },
        function error(errorResponse){
            $scope.message = 'Service is down. Please try again later';
        }
    );
});
```

Here is my logout function call:

```
_userFactory.logout = function(){
    if(AuthFactory.isLogged) {
        AuthFactory.isLogged = false;
        delete AuthFactory.user;

        delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
        delete $window.sessionStorage.user;

        $location.path("/login");
    }
};
```

This is the display of the tasks:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>

    <div class="row">

        <h1>{{tas}}</h1>
        <table class="col-md-2 table-bordered" ng-repeat="task in tasks">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <td>{{task.id}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Task</th>
                <td>{{task.task}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Status</th>
                <td>{{task.status}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Created</th>
                <td>{{task.createdAt}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the backend API i followed the tutorial on: [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/)

**UPDATE**
I ended up creating an interceptor, adding $httpProvider to my app config, and removed the header authorization from my resource calls. Looks like having my Authorization token being read within the api calls was not getting updated.

Interceptor snippet:

```
 authFactory.factory('TokenInterceptor', function($q, $window){
        return {
            request: function(config){
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                if($window.sessionStorage.token) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = $window.sessionStorage.token;
                }
                return config;
            },
            response: function(response){
                if(response.status === 401){
                    console.log('Got a 401');
                }
                return response || $q.when(response);
            }
        };
    });
```

App Config snippet:

```
smlApp.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider, $httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('TokenInterceptor');
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
```

$resource api service call snippet:

```
smlServices.factory('UserTasks', function($resource){
    return $resource("http://koding.io/api/index.php/tasks", {}, {
        get: {method: 'GET', cache: false, isArray: false, headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}},
        save: {method: 'POST', cache: false, isArray: false, headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you use ui-router for routing? If yes there's a cache option that you can try to disable: `$stateProvider.state( 'app', { url: ..., cache: false });`

Comment: I use $routeProvider to determine the templateUrl